# Apache Beam Unbounded Pipeline Windowing

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an unbounded Apache Beam pipeline running in Dataflow that does a very simple set of instructions:

1. It reads a pubsub message (PubsubIO)
2. It pulls the timestamp from the message, pulls data from BigQuery, parses the result into KV values (DoFn)
3. Windows the data into fixed window of 3 seconds (Window PTransform)
4. Groups by key (Ptransform)
5. A DoFn called SplitterLogicFn (DoFn)

What I would hope to see is that as step 2 starts yielding data, each KV would get tagged in the current 3 second fixed window together so that it could get batched in step 4 together alongside the key defined in step 2. However, what Im seeing is that data is not flowing past the GroupByKey step (see image below), which to me means that I dont have the windowing setup correctly.

```
p.apply("Reading input",
        PubsubIO.readMessages()
            .fromSubscription(INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION)
            .withDeadLetterTopic(DL_TOPIC))
        .apply("Reading data",
            ParDo.of(new ReadPlanFromBqFn()))
        .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(3))))
        .apply(GroupByKey.create())
        .apply("Splitting store/item combinations",
            ParDo.of(new SplitItemCombos()))
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Here are a list of other things I tried:

- GroupedIntoBatches:

```
.apply(GroupIntoBatches.<Integer, FieldValueList>ofSize(100)
            .withMaxBufferingDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
```

- Adding triggers:

```
.apply(Window.<FieldValueList>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(3))
                .discardingFiredPanes()
            )
```

In the end nothing gets passed the Group By transform.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Could you try increasing the time duration of [fixed window](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing triggers here, which will tell Beam when the windows will actually fire, not only how they will get grouped together (windows).

Take a look at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-a-trigger.

Comment: I tried that too, using both watermark and/or processing time based triggers but they havent worked